# Finding convergence/abs convergence/divergence of series with trig function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(4n)}{4^n}
$$
I'm doing problems out my book and got stuck on this one. The chapter didn't show any examples with trig functions. I tried doing the $\frac{an+1}{an}$m thing where if it's less then one it's convergent and so on and got as far as $\frac{sin(4n+4)}{4sin(4n)}$ but have no clue what to do with it after that, if that's even the method I should be using.

Comment: You could consider $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(an)}{b^n}$ and use the method Marco Cantarini proposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can note that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\sin\left(4n\right)}{4^{n}}=\textrm{Im}\left(\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\frac{e^{4i}}{4}\right)^{n}\right)
 $$ and since $$\left|\frac{e^{4i}}{4}\right|=\frac{1}{4}
 $$ we can calculate the sum $$\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\frac{e^{4i}}{4}\right)^{n}=\frac{e^{4i}}{4-e^{4i}}
 $$ and so $$\textrm{Im}\left(\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\frac{e^{4i}}{4}\right)^{n}\right)=\textrm{Im}\left(\frac{e^{4i}}{4-e^{4i}}\right)=\frac{4\sin\left(4\right)}{17-8\cos\left(4\right)}\approx-0.13619.$$

Comment: I was typing almost the same considering the two sums ! The result is really nice.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Write the denominator as $4-\cos\left(4\right)-i\sin\left(4\right)$ and multiply $4-\cos\left(4\right)+i\sin\left(4\right)$ the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

This series converges absolutely. Using the fact that $|\sin x|\le 1$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\biggl|\frac{\sin(4n)}{4^n}\biggr|
\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4^n}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4^n}=\frac13.
$$